# OSError: File not found Odoo 13

Tags: odoo-13

OSError: File not found: `library_app\security\library_security.xml`
Im trying to upgrade my module but i'm getting this issue.

This is my manifest

```
{
    'name': 'Library Management',
    'description': 'Manage library book catalogue and lending',
    'author': 'Nicolas Rondon',
    'depends': ['base'],
    'application': True,
    'data': [
        'security/library_security.xml',
        'security/ir.model.access.csv',
        'views/library_menu.xml',
    ]
}
```

The xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<odoo>
  <record id="module_library_category" model="ir.module.category">
    <field name="name">Library</field>
  </record>

  <!-- Library User Group -->
  <record id="library_group_user" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">User</field>
    <field name="category_id"
           ref="module_library_category"/>
    <field name="implied_ids"
           eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
  </record>

  <!-- Library Manager Group -->
  <record id="library_group_manager" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Manager</field>
    <field name="category_id"
           ref="module_library_category"/>
    <field name="implied_ids"
           eval="[(4, ref('library_group_user'))]"/>
    <field name="users"
           eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root')),
                  (4, ref('base.user_admin'))]"/>
  </record>
</odoo>
```

Actually I'm following **Odoo-12-Development-Essentials-Fourth-Edition** to learn Odoo. So my code is very similar to the book.

Comment: can you show the project's directory structure.

Comment: sure here is the structure of my module https://prnt.sc/qx8qk7. Here is project's structure https://prnt.sc/qx8rej Thank you, sorry english it's not my firts language

Comment: I think the xml file is not created properly. You are using pycharm and paycharm shows file extensions like library_security.xml...But in your case it is not showing extension that is why manifest file not getting that file

Comment: Create library_security file again or rename it with library_security.xml

Comment: You are right :D

Answer (score 0):

```
Check the nameofyour model add to _init_ file in pycharm
for example :
from . import Test(name_of_model)
check then file security :
access_Test,access.Test,model_Test,base.group_user,1,1,1,1
check this in manifest:
manifest:
   'data': [
        'security/ir.model.access.csv'
       ]
```